Proving $\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(1-2^{-\frac1n\log_2\frac n{\log n}}\right)^{\frac1{\log_2\frac{n}{\log n}}}=\frac12$
Can someone help me prove that this limit equals $1/2$:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(1-\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{\frac{1}{n}\log_2(\frac{n}{\log(n)})}\right)^{\frac{1}{\log_2(\frac{n}{\log(n)})}}$$
I have tried taking the log, then applying l'Hospital's rule but I get another indeterminate form. I've also tried doing a Taylor expansion, but nothing works.

It reaches 0.5 at a very slow rate. Even at around10^10 the value is somewhat 0.4976, according to Desmos

Are you mixing two kinds of logarithms on purpose ? Please check if what you wrote is OK ?

Yes, they're two types of logarithms. Although you can always change the base so in the limit it could only affect the outcome up to constants

The task is to prove that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1{\log_2\frac n{\ln n}}\ln\left(1-2^{-\frac1n\log_2\frac n{\ln n}}\right)=-\ln(2)$$
or equivalently
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1{\log_2\frac n{\ln n}}\ln\left(1-e^{-\frac1n\ln\frac n{\ln n}}\right)=-\ln(2).$$
First note that (as $n\to\infty$) $$\log_2\frac n{\log n}=\log_2n-\log_2\ln n\sim\log_2n.\tag1\label{eq1A}$$ Similarly, $\ln\frac n{\ln n}\sim\ln n$, from which we derive successively  $\frac1n\ln\frac n{\ln n}\to0$, then $1-e^{-\frac1n\ln\frac n{\ln n}}\sim\frac1n\ln\frac n{\ln n}\sim\frac1n\ln n$, and $$\ln\left(1-e^{-\frac1n\ln\frac n{\ln n}}\right)\sim\ln\left(\frac1n\ln n\right)\sim-\ln n.\tag2\label{eq2A}$$
From \eqref{eq1A} and \eqref{eq2A}, we conclude:
$$\frac1{\log_2\frac n{\ln n}}\ln\left(1-e^{-\frac1n\ln\frac n{\ln n}}\right)\sim\frac1{\log_2n}\left(-\ln n\right)=-\ln(2).$$
